# Error handling on Zip operator RxJava android

Tags: android, rx-java

**What I want**

I wanted to call a

**1** webservice that uploads photo to the server and returns the uploaded link.

**2** webservice to save the returned link by **1st** webservice.

I wanted to combine two observables and get results as same time

**My doubt**

What happens if my **1st** webservice gets fired successfully and **2nd** has encountered an error (eg: Network error, Server error etc)

How can I detect that ? and only retry the **2nd** webservice

**What I can't do**

I can't retry both webservice if **2nd** one fails, because I will end up in sending duplicate files for the **1st** webservice.

**My code**

```
// Upload file (photos,documents etc ):
@POST("some link")
@FormUrlEncoded
Observable<UploadFile> uploadFile(@FieldMap HashMap<String, Object> fields);

// Save link (photos,documents etc ):
@POST("some link")
@FormUrlEncoded
Observable<SaveLink> saveLink(@FieldMap HashMap<String, Object> fields);

// Upload file
Observable<UploadFile> observable = retrofitService.uploadFile(map);
        subscriptionUploadFile = observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<UploadFile>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        CommonFunction.printDebug(TAG, "completed");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(UploadFile model) {

                    }
                });

                // Save link            
                Observable<SaveLink> observable = retrofitService.saveLink(map);
        subscriptionSaveLink = observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<SaveLink>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        CommonFunction.printDebug(TAG, "completed");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(SaveLink model) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Per your description, it's *impossible* to perform the 2 calls at the same time, as the 2nd depends on results from the 1st...

Comment: If 1 gives success and 2 fails , can 2 be only retried?

Comment: You can call your 2nd request from the first one in onNext() depending on its success. And if the 2nd fails, you just handle the error in onError method. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependent continuation is typically done via `flatMap` where you can apply `retry` to the second `Observable`:

```
uploadFile(map)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.flatMap(file -> {
    map.put("URL", file.getURL());
    return saveLink(map).retry(10);
})
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: This seems like calling both webservices separately ... Like I call 1st webservice then OnSuccess I call 2nd webservice

Comment: As already mentioned, you have a dependency on the first service and until you get the result from the first service, you can't call the second one.

Comment: Okay I understood. I will call 2nd webservice after the success of 1st webservice. Thanks for making my problem clear.